# Deleting emails across my Apple devices

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro

How can I sync deleting my emails across Macbook Ipad & iPhone ?

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't exist in iCloud which does syncing across iOS and Apple products. You would need to set up something like an MDM solution like the [Casper suite](http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite/) to automate this.